# cloud-init use metada as variable

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cloud-init

I would like to use cloud-init medata as value in module but it's seem not possible.

For exemple to setup ntp, local mirror, etc..

The following configuration file do not work.

```
#cloud-config
## template:jinja
ntp:
  servers:
    - {{ ds.meta_data.meta.ntp2 }}
```

I checked that the metadata and she still exist.

```
$ cloud-init query -f "{{ ds.meta_data.meta.ntp2 }}"
ntp.local
```

Do you know how can I do that?

many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Put the template line before the cloud-config line:

```yaml
## template: jinja
#cloud-config
ntp:
  servers:
    - {{ ds.meta_data.meta.ntp2 }}
```

Comment: Weird. I don't have that key, but if I use `{{ ds.meta_data.local_hostname }}`, I get the results you're expecting. Does your key live only in `/run/cloud-init/instance-data-sensitive.json` and not `/run/cloud-init/instance-data.json` ? If so, you're hitting https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1931392 which is fixed but not yet released.

Comment: Also note I just realized I had a typo: `## template:jinja` is supposed to be `## template: jinja`